# Display alert when a button is clicked in CK Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

How can I display an alert with ckeditor if a button is pressed?

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".cke_button__bold").click(function () {
          editor.on("CKEDITOR.cke_button__bold",CKEDITOR.cke_button_on);

          function handleAfterCommandExec(evt){
                var commandName = CKEDITOR.command.cke_button__bold;
                // For 'bold' commmand
                if (commandName == 'cke_button__on')
                {
                    alert("Bold button pressed!");

                }
         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

## [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
> parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
> selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
> future.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on('click','.cke_button__bold',function () {
         if($(this).hasClass('cke_button_on'))//checking for enable only
         {
           alert("Click event occure when only enable");
         }
     });
});
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/323/)

Comment: thanks this function return bold button enable and disable time .i wnat only enable time

Comment: alignments what can i do. if it is possible

Comment: @AnuKrishna i don't understand. Clarify this

Comment: This is not the right (optimum) way. You should use the [`editor#beforeCommandExec`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-beforeCommandExec) event.

Comment: Ok @Reinmar why don't you show us right approach with Example.

Comment: How to load ckeditor in android tablets. if any code is there

Comment: if ckeditor bold button enabled .then the button color can be changed what to do? pls hlp

Comment: How to alert the selected and unselected  of ckeditor buttons